# Using SQLMigration Assistant Tool from Access give me data import error, how I detect the failing rows?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I need to convert an access file to SQL server so I can import data to a new application...
I've tried different times but I got the following error after the completition

```
Error occurred during data migration.
See the log for the detailed information. The provider could not determine the Double value. For example, the row was just created, the default for the Double column was not available, and the consumer had not yet set a new Double value.
```

The version of the application is

[image]

And the table structure is quite simple

[image]

Is there a way to detect the failing row or do I have to manually scan the access file?

Comment: And the log says ..?

Comment: Nothing.... but I just found... there were CalulatedColumns.... I just removed them and I'll apply the calculation in the new app.